# Inserting dynamic pivot Result into Temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the date and script below which calculate sales by item and year. It works fine 
But when I try to insert the result into temp table so that the temp table can be uses in another query. I have the following error

```
CREATE TABLE #TBL  (Dates DATE, [Year] INT, Amt MONEY,Item Varchar(100))
INSERT INTO #TBL VALUES 
('2018-06-01',2018,34,'Milk'),('2018-07-01',2018,99,'Rice'),('2018-08-01',2018,77,'Rice'),('2018-09-01',2018,26,'Rice'),
('2018-10-01',2018,75,'Orange'),('2018-11-01',2018,94,'Grapes'),('2018-12-01',2018,80,'Grapes'),('2019-01-01',2019,9,'Grapes'),
('2019-02-01',2019,52,'Milk'),('2019-03-01',2019,28,'Orange'),('2019-04-01',2019,61,'Orange'),('2019-05-01',2019,51,'Milk');

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME( Item) 
            FROM #TBL 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
 SET @query = 
      'SELECT 
       * 
       INTO #Final
       FROM (
     SELECT [Year],Amt ,Item
    FROM #TBL ) FG
    PIVOT
    (
    SUM(Amt) FOR Item IN ('+@cols+')
    ) pv'
EXEC(@query)
select * from #Final
 ;DROP TABLE #TBL
```

error Invalid object name '#Final'.

Is it possible to insert data from dynamic pivot into a temp table

Comment: I would suggest just using `select . . . into` in the pivot query. The simplest method is a global temporary table or a real table in your dataset, rather than a temporary table.

Comment: A temporary table declared in a dynamic statement will only persist for the duration of that statement. If you need to retain the data, and `INSERT` it into a table, you'll need to create and define a *permanent* object. Considering you don't appear to use the table `#Final` further in your query though, why do you need it?

Comment: @Larnu I need it because it a part of stored procedure that i will use to join to other table in the stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this Query...**

First Drop the #Final if exists....

then create the #Final table...

then Perfrom your old Query.....will not give **error Invalid object name '#Final'.** this type of error

```
CREATE TABLE #TBL  (Dates DATE, [Year] INT, Amt MONEY,Item Varchar(100))
INSERT INTO #TBL VALUES 
('2018-06-01',2018,34,'Milk'),('2018-07-01',2018,99,'Rice'),('2018-08-01',2018,77,'Rice'),('2018-09-01',2018,26,'Rice'),
('2018-10-01',2018,75,'Orange'),('2018-11-01',2018,94,'Grapes'),('2018-12-01',2018,80,'Grapes'),('2019-01-01',2019,9,'Grapes'),
('2019-02-01',2019,52,'Milk'),('2019-03-01',2019,28,'Orange'),('2019-04-01',2019,61,'Orange'),('2019-05-01',2019,51,'Milk');



IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Final', 'U') IS NOT NULL
/*Then it exists*/
DROP TABLE #Final


CREATE TABLE #Final  ([Year] INT, Amt MONEY,Item Varchar(100))


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME( Item) 
            FROM #TBL 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
 SET @query = 
      'SELECT 
       * 
       INTO #Final
       FROM (
     SELECT [Year],Amt ,Item
    FROM #TBL ) FG
    PIVOT
    (
    SUM(Amt) FOR Item IN ('+@cols+')
    ) pv'
EXEC(@query)
select * from #Final

DROP TABLE #TBL
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a global temp table with the double-# syntax: INTO ##Final, which will have scope outside the dynamic sql